# Error installing mod-wsgi on Apache server

Tags: python-2.7, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm installing mod-wsgi and following [this guide](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide) when I get up to this step:

> To install the Apache module into the standard location for Apache
>   modules as dictated by Apache for your installation, run:
>
> ```
> make install
> ```

however when I run `sudo make install` I get this error

```
wrong number of arguments to instdso.sh
Usage: instdso.sh SH_LIBTOOL-value dso-name path-to-modules
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

I tried searching the web for this error but couldn't find anything and mod-wsgi's installation issues page doesn't talk about this error at all. Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 21):

I realized this is an old question, but in case someone else stumbles upon this...

Try to run ./configure again and retry sudo make install.  It fixed the problem for me.  Good luck.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks